# IIS data Base64 Format image too long string

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, base64

I have a data in my project; it is a Base64 Format Image.
When i run it in Visual Studio, my 
img src:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

but when it is published in IIS, the string is too long and the image not transparent:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

for converting bitmap image to base64 i use method:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                return string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}",Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes));
            }
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Those are different images, are you sure you are publishing the file?

Comment: i updated information

Comment: The first is 16x16, the second is 24x24, though they look the same they're not the same image file.

Comment: But how it can be?  I just publish the project and coding becomes 3 times longer, No code changes